# Browse an image file and display it in a kivy window

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I am a beginner in Kivy and trying to browse an image file using kivy fileChooser and then displaying it on the window. Bellow you find my code but it wouldn't do the task. It just displays '?PNG' on the console. Please, check this out with me !

```
    import kivy
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.uix.image import Image
    import os

    Builder.load_string("""
    <MyWidget>:
        id: my_widget
        Button
            text: "open"
            on_release: my_widget.open(filechooser.path, 
    filechooser.selection)
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser
            on_selection: my_widget.selected(filechooser.selection)
    """)

    class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
        def open(self, path, filename):
            with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as f:
                print f.read()

        def selected(self, filename):
            return Image(source=filename[0])

    class MyApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return MyWidget()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
I exclude the open button, and just display it when selected.
So we add an `Image` widget, and set its source when selected.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""
<MyWidget>:
    id: my_widget
    FileChooserListView:
        id: filechooser
        on_selection: my_widget.selected(filechooser.selection)
    Image:
        id: image
        source: ""
""")


class MyWidget(BoxLayout):

    def selected(self,filename):
        self.ids.image.source = filename[0]


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

This is just a minimal example. It will throw an error if you go a directory up. So you need to handle that.

Easy fix:

```
class MyWidget(BoxLayout):

    def selected(self,filename):
        try:
            self.ids.image.source = filename[0]
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: @InesTlili you are wellcome